# jQuery - Find every header 3 tag, grab every word within it and add it to the header 3 element as a class

Tags: jquery, text, find, addclass

In a previous question I asked something similar which was solved thanks to such a great community. In that question I had to find certain words within an element and assign them as a class to the same tag.

In this question I want to find every 'h3' tag within the .products class, take all of the words within it and assign them to the same 'h3' element as the class.

For example:

```
<h3>Hello World</h3>
```

would become:

```
<h3 class="Hello World">Hello World</h3>
```

and another 'h3' tag within another .product class on the same page would become:

```
<h3>Sup!</h3> 
<h3 class="Sup!">Sup!</h3>
```

I have targeted the h3 tags with ease using:

```
jQuery(".product h3").text();
```

and have even used:

```
jQuery("product h3").find();
jQuery(".product").find("h3").addClass("lol");
```

But off course that would add "lol" to every 'h3' on the page when I want it to take the words within the element itself and use that.

I just can't figure out once I have found the information how to I add the words as a class to the same element.

Can anyone help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery('.product h3').addClass(function(){
    return this.innerHTML;
})
```

Comment: I feel so dumb. I thought about using innerHTML but never tried it. Thanks Karl, you solved it in a second. Another really useful piece of information that broadens my knowledge in jQuery! I hope to become as good as coders like you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('h3.product').addClass(function(){
  return $(this).text();
});
```